# Converting List to Stream and vice-versa

Tags: c#

I am having trouble of passing large data from WCF to consumer. I have set all the needed configuration but still encountering Insufficient Memomy exception. Now the other way to solve this problem is to convert the list object to Stream. I have search on how to convert the Object to Stream but can't find exactly what I want. For example I have an Object like this `IList<Person>`I need to convert this to `Stream` and from `Stream` to `IList<Person>`. Any help please.

Comment: Well what format do you want that stream to take? Binary serialization of some form? JSON in a particular encoding?

Comment: Well, I am new to Stream, I need to return the Stream object without using serialization.

Comment: In order to create a stream you have to represent somehow your objects as array of bytes. You can't do that without some form of serialization.

Comment: Indeed, that's pretty much the definition of serialization.